# Java/Android String to Byte Conversion

Tags: java, android, string, byte

I have a String `str = "0x01"`.
I want to convert this string into byte exactly as it is.

I tried doing `str.getBytes()` and `EncodingUtils.getAsciiBytes(str)` but it gives byte value of each character I suppose.

I want byte variable to have value as 0x01.

Any idea how do we do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
byte b = Byte.decode("0x01");
```

Comment: I went originally with Integer because I wasn't sure Byte.decode existed; there are/have been minor differences between the wrapper class features.

Comment: I see. Might depend on the API version.